# On OSX, Instead of localhost:8090 how can I use just localhost with Jetty?

Tags: macos, webserver, jetty, localhost, port

I use an external API where a domain/key-pair is needed, and the domain-name doesn't tolerate the port. So for my local development environment I would need to be able to use an URL without the port. I'm using Jetty.

Any ideas if / how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Some of what I'm writing might be obvious to you, but I prefer to be explicit)*

When you say you want to have a URL without the port, that means that you actually want to run on port 80.

When a URL doesn't include a port, the default port for the scheme is implied. The default port for `http` is 80, so `http://www.google.com/` is the same as `http://www.google.com:80/`

So, to have your Jetty server available at `http://localhost/`, you need to have it accessible on port 80.

There are 3 broad options:

1. Actually start it on port 80. However, on most operating systems only the admin (root) user can start services on ports lower than 1024, so you would need to start/run jetty as `root`. On OSX, that can be done by running Jetty with `sudo`. There are more complicated ways of doing this, but if you're just running on your own desktop `sudo` is the easiest. You can read about some of the other ways here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Port80
2. Use operating system features to map requests for port 80 to the port you're running Jetty on. On Linux (and other similar operating systems) you can use `ipchains` or `iptables` (the *Port80* page I listed above describes these), on Mac OSX `ipfw` can do the sme thing. Here's an [example for running Tomcat on port 80 on OSX](http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.com.au/2011/05/port-forwarding-80-to-8080-for-tomcat.html), exactly the same instructions will work for Jetty - In your case just change the `8080` to `8090`.
3. Put another server (like Apache HTTPd) in front of Jetty. Run that server on port 80, and configure it to proxy requests through to your Jetty server. See: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_mod_proxy

Option #2 is probably what you want, but you'll need to decide for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [document](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Jetty) which I just found on the Jetty website, you can configure ports in jetty.xml:

Then googling 'jetty.xml port' led me to this page (because I wanted a syntax example):
[Howto/Configure Jetty](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/jetty.xml_usage),

which had one, but also led me to this command-line usage where they specify the port from command line when starting Jetty:

`java -Djetty.port=80 -jar start.jar etc/jetty.xml`

Comment: You'll probably have to sudo that java line to run on port 80.

Comment: yeah, the only way to can drop that port off is to run it on port 80 for normal http://